# An ifelse statement that checks a variable for a letter

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr

I apologize if this is basic. I am trying perform hex to dec and dec to hex functions on a variable in a data frame in R. I need to "sort" my dataframe into two variables, those which have a character string that contain a letter, and those that do not (i.e. if they are in hex or in dec).

My solution is to create new variables with mutate and an ifelse statement, but with my code below it appears to not recognize that any character string contains a letter.

df$PITnumF contains this:

3D91BF15B9C2D,
985120013429805

My attempt to mutate/ifelse

```
mutate(df, h2df = ifelse(df$PITnumF %in% c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H"
                                       , "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", 
                                       "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"),
                     (.hex.to.dec(df$PITnumF)), (.dec.to.hex(df$PITnumF))))
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: When using `mutate` (and other `dplyr` verbs), you should not use `df$` inside the verb. Instead, `mutate(df, h2df = ifelse(PITnumF %in% ...))`. While it tends to work "just fine" here, it will fail miserably when you have a pipe more than one verb long and/or use `group_by`. BTW, you can determine if something has non-numeric characters with `grepl("\\D", string)`.

Comment: `ifelse(grepl("[A-F]|[a-f]", PITnumF), .hex.to.dec(PITnumF), .dec.to.hex(PITnumF))` ought to do it. I hope you don't have any hexadecimal numbers with no letters in though!